# Are there dSLR cameras which can take movies without a rolling shutter artifact?

Tags: video

Most cameras have a problem with movie recording due to the way pixels are read sequentially off the sensor, rather than all at once.

Are there any dSLR (or otherwise high-quality image) cameras whose movies don't exhibit the rolling shutter artifact (also known as "jello-y")?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Mastering [HD Video with your DSLR](http://www.neocamera.com/article.php?id=mastering_hd_video_dslr), the author claims that only CMOS sensors suffer from the rolling shutter effect. A [quick search](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?size=slr&sensortype=ccd) shows there are currently NO DSLR with CCD sensors, so you'll have to settle for something smaller.

That does not leave many cameras that distinguish themselves for image quality. A few like the Olympus ZX-1, Nikon P7000, Canon S95, Canon G12 and Fuji F200 EXR.

Comment: CMOS or CCD? An even quicker search would rapidly assure me that just about every dSLR in the 35mm format is CMOS based... :)

Comment: @John - Good catch. Corrected, it made no sense given the previous sentence.